# How to generate gRPC services and reuse existed DTOs in java with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

Is it possible to describe some services in .proto files which use the existed DTOs & generate the service classes with gradle?

I'm developing client SDK for some server. The current communication layer based on gRPC but I don't want to expose the implementation details (those ugly gRPC messages classes) to the end user. So the public API represented with POJOs.

The existed solution make some conversions between two types of DTOs with custom converters. And this is quite annoying - copy tones of properties just to beautify the public API. So I'm looking a way to reuse the POJO on gRPC layer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf really needs those messages in order to be told what to serialize. So while there are some ways to serialize your own message types (like MethodDescriptor.Marshaller), if you want to use Protobuf you'll need to copy between the different types of objects.